# Box-shadow on parent has to ignore children margin

Tags: html, css

Let's say we have this simple markup with the following styles:

```css
.outer {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px red;
  padding: 2px;
}

.inner {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<span class="outer">
  <span class="inner">Content</span>
</span>
```

This results in the `.outer` span have the width of the `.inner` which includes a `25px margin`. What I would like to happen is for `.outer` to have the `box-shadow` spread over its own `width` excluding `inner`s `margin`.

Is that at all possible ?

Comment: if you apply the box-shadow to inner and margin to outer the result could be right?

Comment: spans are used as inline elements. If you want the containing span to be narrower than its conained elements, then you should not be using spans at all here.

Comment: *its own width excluding inners margin.* --> this is not logica; because that margin is defining the width

Answer (score 0):

How about adding box-shadow, padding to `.inner` instead of `.outer`

```css
.inner {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px red;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<span class="outer">
  <span class="inner">Content</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that as I don't have control over `.inner` in my app. I can only control what happens to `.outer`

Comment: @Asabovesobelow You can control children using CSS.